# How to use more than 3 virtual disks in Linux using CentOS and XenServer

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machines, xenserver

I've attached 5 virtual disks to a Virtual Machine in Citrix XenServer.  The VM has the xs-tools installed.  Initially it said that it couldn't add so many disks.   After I installed the xs-tools, it let me add all the disks.

But `/dev` doesn't show all the disks.  It shows these:

```
/dev/xvda
/dev/xvdb
/dev/xvdc
/dev/cdrom
```

Perhaps it is bound by the limits of an IDE bus? (3 disks + CD-ROM)  If so, how does one change the VM to use SCSI?

**Edit:**
[According to the documentation:](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/5.0.0/1.0/en_gb/guest.html)

> 2.6.3. VM Block Devices
>
> In the PV Linux case, block devices are passed through as PV devices.
>   XenServer does not attempt to emulate SCSI or IDE, but instead
>   provides a more suitable interface in the virtual environment in the
>   form of xvd* devices. It is also possible to get an sd* device using
>   the same mechanism, where the PV driver inside the VM takes over the
>   SCSI device namespace. This is not desirable so it is best to use xvd*
>   where possible for PV guests (this is the default for Debian and
>   RHEL).
>
> For Windows or other fully virtualized guests, XenServer emulates an
>   IDE bus in the form of an hd* device. When using Windows, installing
>   the Citrix Tools for Virtual Machines installs a special PV driver
>   that works in a similar way to Linux, except in the fully virtualized
>   environment.

Still, with 5 virtual disks attached, I don't see the other xvd devices.

**Edit #2:** (attached requested info)

**Host Machine:**

```
XenServer 6.1
Linux version 2.6.32.43-0.4.1.xs1.6.10.777.170770xen (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)) #1 SMP Wed Apr 17 05:52:03 EDT 2013
```

**Guest Machine:**

```
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Linux version 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu May 16 20:59:36 UTC 2013
```

**Output of 'fdisk -l' on Guest Machine:**

Note, the disk beyond the first 3 attached are not displaying -- there should be 4 100GB disks. (There are a total of 5 disks displayed in XenCenter -- 16GB, 100GB, 100GB, 100GB, 100GB)

```
Disk /dev/xvdb: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xfb6c95b9

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdb1               1       13054   104856223+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/xvda: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2088 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e5f41

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/xvda2              64        2089    16264192   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/xvdc: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xed249ced

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvdc1               1       13054   104856223+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_blue-lv_root: 14.6 GB, 14571012096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1771 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_blue-lv_swap: 2080 MB, 2080374784 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 252 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

I see that the Linux versions say SMP.  The Guest VM doesn't say "xen" in the name.  However, I have already run `yum install kernel-xen`.  Could be a clue?

Comment: Please provide CentOS, Linux Kernel & XenServer Version. Could you also add the output of "fdisk -l"?

Comment: Added the requested info

Comment: Have you rebooted your VM after citrix xs-tools installation?
Normally xs-tools will install a xen-enabled linux kernel, therefore also check your bootloader configuration (xen-kernel entry).

Comment: Is there a `/proc/xen` directory?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I run into this occasionally and the errors are similar.  Verify you have increased the number of loop devices allowed.  It may seem unrelated but the instantiation of a VM can be blocked by this.  Verify you have increased the loop devices in /etc/modprobe.d/loop.conf  using  options loop max_loop=64

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. 
I think you will see error message in /var/log/messages

```
blkfront: your disk configuration is incorrect, please use an xvd device instead
```

Disks in GUI are /dev/hda, /dev/hdb, /dev/hdc, but on RHEL < 6 it is /dev/xvda/ etc... 
Disk can be added manually from cli, if you name it as /dev/xvd .

Found this: http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1692261 Check Albert Czarnecki answeres.

"As like I said your machine is running in HVM mode. You must run command and change from HVM to PV:
xe vm-param-set uuid=your_machine PV-bootloader=pygrub HVM-boot-policy="" and then run again machine."

Check also https://www.linuxnet.ch/xenserver-howto-convert-hvm-to-pv-rhelsuse/

Edit: I tried that, and now all disks are visible and system is PV .

Quick summary (may vary):

```
xe vm-list name-label=SERVERNAME params=uuid 
uuid ( RO)    : 2a596adf-ccf4-6469-cf89-702d723cfbb9

UUID=`xe vm-list name-label=SERVERNAME params=uuid | cut -d ":" -f 2`
```

Check if PV or HVM

```
xe vm-param-list uuid=2a596adf-ccf4-6469-cf89-702d723cfbb9 | egrep "PV-bootloader|HVM-boot-policy"
xe vm-param-list uuid=`echo ${UUID}` | egrep "PV-bootloader|HVM-boot-policy"
HVM-boot-policy ( RW): BIOS order
PV-bootloader ( RW): 
PV-bootloader-args ( RW):
```

Set PV:

```
xe vm-param-set uuid=2a596adf-ccf4-6469-cf89-702d723cfbb9 PV-bootloader=pygrub HVM-boot-policy=""
xe vm-param-set uuid=`echo ${UUID}` PV-bootloader=pygrub HVM-boot-policy=""
```

After reboot:

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | grep xvd
Disk /dev/xvdb: 51.5 GB, 51539607552 bytes
Disk /dev/xvde: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes   <------ YEAAAAAH "test disk 1GB visible for os"
Disk /dev/xvda: 16.1 GB, 16106127360 bytes
/dev/xvda1   *           1          13      102400   83  Linux
/dev/xvda2              13         274     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/xvda3             274        1959    13528064   8e  Linux LVM
Disk /dev/xvdc: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes
```

Comment: I just successfully finished migration of 7 RHEL 6 servers from HVM to PV. Does exists better template from Citrix ?

Comment: Interesting, mine has both the HVM-boot-policy and the PV-bootloader set. I cleared the HVM-boot-policy and rebooted.  Now I just have the PV-bootloader=pygrub. But it's not working yet.  I'll keep messing with this.

Comment: :( Any error message in dmesg, /var/log/messages ?